# Transposition of column values into rows based on a value criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A             B           C         D            E       F       G
1                    Sale 1     Sale 2    Sale 3
2    Product A           0       150       400                 Sale 2  Sale 3
3    Product B       1.000         0       300         Sale 1          Sale 3
4    Product C          50        200       70         Sale 1  Sale 2  Sale 3
5    Product D         800          0        0         Sale 1
```

In **Columns B:D** you can see the Sales for each product.

In **Columns E:G** I want to show in which Sale the product was sold. Therefore, the Sale which is `<> 0` should be shown.

So far used this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B2:$D2<>0,),0))
```

but it only works if a product is sold only once (unique).
Once the product appears in more sales as for example Product A this
formula gives me only back the Sale 2 but it leaves out the Sale 3.

Is there a way to list each sale next to the product.
Something like htis:

```
Transposition IF value <>0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2 and copied across and down to suit:

```
=IF(B2>0,B$1,"")
```

`B2` is not anchored so will adjust to C2 etc when copied across (and B3 etc when copied down - equivalent to RC[-3]) whereas the row for `B$1` is anchored so will not change (but the column will change in line with that for `B2`).

Comment: I was slow by 10 seconds :)